# Embed into reactjs

Tags: reactjs

How do I embed this into an ReactJS application?

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_c8487"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://se.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL diagram</span></a> från TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "sv_SE",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_c8487"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

Use like this

```
const myScript = `<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div id="tradingview_c8487"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://se.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">AAPL diagram</span></a> från TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  new TradingView.widget(
  {
  "width": 980,
  "height": 610,
  "symbol": "NASDAQ:AAPL",
  "interval": "D",
  "timezone": "Etc/UTC",
  "theme": "light",
  "style": "1",
  "locale": "sv_SE",
  "toolbar_bg": "#f1f3f6",
  "enable_publishing": false,
  "allow_symbol_change": true,
  "container_id": "tradingview_c8487"
}
  );
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->`

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html : myScript} />;
```

[here is the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html)